# Printing the values of a dictionary when its key is equal to the value of a list element

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this code below and I want to print the `combo[values]` for any `combo[keys]` in combo that are equal to `numb[i]`

```
numb = [5, 7, 49, 11, 13]    
combo  = {45 : (-1002,-1023), 49 : (-9999,-2347), 20 : (-1979, -1576), 13 : (-6000,-3450), 110     : (-2139, -8800), 7 : (-6754,-9087) }
```

How do I do it, please?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Not all values in `numb` are present in `combo`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ah, missed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean loop through `numb` and print any key if present?

Two options; with a loop:

```
for key in numb:
    if key in combo:
        print combo[key]
```

which can be expressed as a list comprehension too, to produce a list:

```
[combo[key] for key in numb if key in combo]
```

Or with [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
for key in combo.viewkeys() & numb:
    print combo[key]
```

again as a list comprehension too:

```
[combo[key] for key in combo.viewkeys() & numb]
```

Demo:

```
>>> numb = [5, 7, 49, 11, 13]    
>>> combo  = {45 : (-1002,-1023), 49 : (-9999,-2347), 20 : (-1979, -1576), 13 : (-6000,-3450), 110     : (-2139, -8800), 7 : (-6754,-9087) }
>>> [combo[key] for key in numb if key in combo]
[(-6754, -9087), (-9999, -2347), (-6000, -3450)]
>>> [combo[key] for key in combo.viewkeys() & numb]
[(-9999, -2347), (-6000, -3450), (-6754, -9087)]
```

What route you take depends on the size of `combo` and `numb`, and on whether `numb` could be a `set` as well. If `numb` could be a set, the `dict.viewkeys()` could optimize the intersection operation by using the smaller of the two and will most probably be the faster option, especially for larger datasets.

Comment: I think you mean `if key in combo` and `combo[key]`

Comment: @user3449019: glad you found both answers helpful. You can only pick *one* of them as the *accepted* answer, however.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [v for k, v in combo.items() if k in numb]
[(-6754, -9087), (-6000, -3450), (-9999, -2347)]
```

I think that is what you meant?

Comment: -0.  `k in numb` does a linear search.  When combined with the for loop this will end up performing in quadradic time. OP did not ask for the best performing code, however it seems wasteful here because there are alternatives that perform better that are also clear and concise.